# How to setup existing asp site in ISS with MS Access database?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, iis

I need to migrate an old .asp site onto our new server (Server Essentials 2016). 
The site runs off an Access database and is currently hosted in IIS on a windows 7 pro machine. 
I have enabled asp.net 4.6 on the new server and copied the whole website from the old server (Windows 7 Pro) into an equivalent directory on the new server, (C:\inetpub\wwwroot - I know it's not best practice to store the site here but I am eliminating variables to get the site working - once it works, I'll move it...). 
Plain HTML pages now work fine, so the sites folder is clearly accessible but any page that needs to access the database gives an error 500 - both from the server's own browser and from other PC's on the network... The site and it's database are both in the same wwwroot folder and have an identical filepath to that on the windows 7 machine so the only thing different is the computer name and OS. 
I have multiple other (php) sites running on the new server but cannot get this asp site to work!

What am I doing wrong? Short of rewriting the whole site in php I'm stuck!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by providing the actual error. Google _debug asp_. Come back if you can tell us more than _error 500_, that's one of the most generic errors on the web.

Comment: I know error 500 is so vague it's almost pointless, but the fact the same site does work on the old server suggests that the issue is with the server set up rather than the code - have I missed something with IIS itself? General html pages, even with a .asp extension work fine, it's only pages which need to access the database that give an error...

Comment: We can tell you that if you provide us more details in the error. Now, it can be anything, from not properly setting up Access to missing dependencies to locale-dependent code and a difference in locale to a variety of configuration issues. As said, come back when you can tell us more than _error 500_, start with basic debugging. Now, we can only guess, and this isn't the place for wild guesses or debugging tutorials.

Comment: OK so I've enabled detailed error responses for the error 500 code and got "Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0131'

Disallowed Parent Path" So then I enabled parent paths (again, best practice or not, I just want to get this thing working...) and now get "ADODB.Command error '800a0e7a'

Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

Comment: I've searched for this fault code and the answer seems to be to enable 32-bit applications in the application pool but if I do this I get error 500.19 for all pages, not just those requiring database access?

Comment: Sounds like you have an issue with your Access installation on the server. If you have 32-bit Access and 64-bit ASP, you can indeed fix it by enabling 32-bit applications, but you can also fix it by installing 64-bits Access or the 64-bits Access Database Engine.

Comment: Hmmm, I've installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) but this has made no difference... I still get "ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e7a'

Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I needed to change the connections file from "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" to "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" None of the error messages hinted at this but we got there in the end!

So to recap for anyone else in this situation:

Step 1: In IIS highlight the site in the left hand pane and double click the "ASP" icon, then change "Enable Parent Paths" to "True"

Step 2: Download and install the Microsoft Access Database Engine (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Step 3: Change the code in your connections file to "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

Thanks for the guidance!